# Flume event modification

Tags: flume

How can I add timestamp to the front of the each event of Flume?
say I have this log, but I also want to addd timestamp

> 127.0.0.1 - frank [10/Oct/2000:13:55:36 -0700] "GET /apache_pb.gif HTTP/1.0" 200 2326
>   **2016-05-95** 127.0.0.1 - frank [10/Oct/2000:13:55:36 -0700] "GET /apache_pb.gif HTTP/1.0" 200 2326

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this question by using Morphline, adding these functions below, where timestamp is added to the beginning of each event of flume. 
`{
          addCurrentTime { field : timestamp }
      },

      {
        setValues {
      _result = "@{timestamp}|@{message}"
        }
      },`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean to add a timestamp to the beginning of the event body bytes, then there isn't a pre-canned interceptor to do what you're asking (the search and replace interceptor can't replace with a dynamic value such as date).

However, writing an interceptor to prefix each event body with the current timestamp should be trivial enough.

Check the source code for existing interceptors as an example, compile your code and deploy the jar into a new folder named `$FLUME_HOME/plugins.d/my-plugins/lib/my-plugin.jar`

Here's a link to the current source for the standard flume interceptors:

- https://github.com/apache/flume/tree/trunk/flume-ng-core/src/main/java/org/apache/flume/interceptor

But essentially you just need to create a class that implement `Interceptor` interface, and create an `Interceptor.Builder` implementation too.

Comment: I see , Thanks Chris for comment, as far as I know there are two ways to do that, one that you specified above, writing my own class that implement Interceptor, and the other way is use morphline.

Comment: I created TimeStampClass and Builder and I placed jar into this /usr/lib/flume-ng/lib/ directory. But it doesn't find `ava.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.flume.interceptor.TimestampBodyInterceptor$Builder`

Comment: Can you post a listing of your jar contents? `unzip -l myjar.jar`

Answer (score 0):

You can use Flume Interceptors: https://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html#flume-interceptors
to modify events.

You can write your own classes that achieve the functionality you are looking for or you can use Morphline interceptors, too.

If it's not a requirement that you change the body, you can just use timestamp interceptor to add the timestamp to the headers.

Comment: Hi bessbd, thanks for the response. I saw that , and I tried with that but it only works with adding  the timestamp to the header not the content of each line of  file.I need to add timestamp to each event, but sounds like flume itself have no function for this, I either need to write my morpline conf of my interceptor class.

Comment: Hi Farslan,
Depending on your use-case, it might be sufficient to have that data in the headers: if you use hdfs sink for example, you can add it to the path you are writing to and when you do the processing, you use the additional data you have in the filename.

Comment: I created TimeStampClass and Builder and I placed jar into this /usr/lib/flume-ng/lib/ directory. But it doesn't find `ava.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.flume.interceptor.TimestampBodyInterceptor$Builde‌​r` Am I missing some?

Comment: This is my conf where I call the class, but couldn't paste the code saying too large ``agent1.sources.webserver-log-source.interceptors.i4.type = org.apache.flume.interceptor.TimestampBodyInterceptor$Builder
#agent1.sources.webserver-log-source.interceptors.i4.separator = ,

Comment: `public static class Builder implements Interceptor.Builder{

  private String seperator;
  
  public void configure(Context ctx) {

   this.seperator = ctx.getString(Constants.SEPERATOR);
   
  }

  public Interceptor build() {
   
   return new EventTimestampAdder(this.seperator);
  }
  
  
  
 }`

Comment: and this is how I implement interceptor `public class EventTimestampAdder implements Interceptor {`

Comment: I suggest you take a look at https://reviews.apache.org/r/51244/diff/7#index_header to see how to implement your own interceptor, because the things you have pasted seem correct.